# The end of my watch on IPS

Tags: discussion, moderation

Hey, everyone.

Over the past few months, I think a few folks might have noticed that I've gradually become less and less present on Interpersonal Skills. While I've continued to handle flags (albeit at a reduced pace), I've been pretty absent on meta and in chat, and I've been virtually invisible on the main site. I've been slowly drifting away from the community, and so I finally decided to step down as a moderator here.

It happened for a whole bunch of reasons. I'm taking an increased academic workload this year, which is super awesome but also super draining. I'm also trying to better serve my other sites; for instance, we have some ongoing community promotion efforts on Astronomy that I'm really excited about. Finally, moderating a site like IPS is just kinda exhausting, period. It's definitely been the most challenging site for me to moderate, and I think I need a rest.

The mod team has decided that for the immediate future, they'll be just fine without me and won't need a replacement moderator. The flag queue has been fairly manageable as of late, so no need to worry about that.

It's been an incredible 18 months. I'm proud of what we've all built, and I'm happy with where the site is and where it's going in the future. I'll still be around on IPS, and I hope to be a part of that future - just in a slightly less stressful position. :-)

I also want to add a huge thanks to everyone I've worked with along the way - Catija, Tinkeringbell, AJ, EmC, John, and the community team. I've been happy and fortunate to have had you all.

See you all around.

Comment: So long to your moderatorship HDE. I've been very appreciative of the work you've done as a moderator in the year that I've been here. You've been reasonable, level-headed, and fair. I think I speak for most of the community when I say that we'll miss your moderation contributions. Best of luck in your studies and your moderation elsewhere!

Comment: You have been (and will further be) missed around here! I hope you experience good fortune in all of your other endeavors!

Comment: Thank you HDE for all your contributions here (and for helping me get up to speed when I first joined the mod team)! Best wishes for your other sites, and of course we'll be happy to see you around anytime :)

Comment: Thank you for your support in building this site. Wishing you the best for your future.

Answer (score 19):

You've been a amazing mod. I'm certain you'll be an amazing "regular" user as well.

Best of luck for your studies and hope we'll see you around!